# Can't include weblink containing '-' character with hyperref in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I am using a BibTeX bibliography with the `h-physrev` bibliography style and want the Journal, Volume, Pages and Year to be clickable links to the paper's DOI. I am using the `hyperref` package to add the links in the `.bib` file as shown in MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Sample Text \cite{Ref1}

\bibliographystyle{h-physrev}
\bibliography{Refs}
\end{document}
```

with accompanying `.bib` file

```
  @article{Ref1,
  author  =  {Author},
  journal =  {\href{Link1}{Journal}},
  volume  =  {\href{Link1}{Volume}},
  pages   =  {\href{Link1}{Pages}},
  year    =  {\href{Link1}{Year}},
  title   =  {\href{Link1}{Title}},
 }
```

However, if the url includes the "-" character for the `pages` entry, the script will not compile.

```
 @article{Ref1,
  author  =  {Author},
  journal =  {\href{Link1}{Journal}},
  volume  =  {\href{Link1}{Volume}},
  pages   =  {\href{Link-1}{Pages}},
  year    =  {\href{Link1}{Year}},
  title   =  {\href{Link1}{Title}},
 }
```

The "-" symbol works in the urls for all other entries. Is this a bug and is there a workaround?

Comment: `h-physrev` is not a known bibtex style. Where do you get that style?

Comment: I think you are basically misusing bibtex here. For pages it is explicitly looking for the `-` because it expects the page number to be on the form `4-16`, say. Remember `bibtex` knows hardly anything about LaTeX, to it just sees `\href{Link-1}{Pages}` as a string and splits it at the `-`.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but you could solve the issue by replacing an especially "nasty" DOI (with Ö>§%&-ß#!) by their short DOI: https://shortdoi.org/, which does not contain any "-" or other problematic things.

Comment: I agree with daleif. BibTeX assumes that your `.bib` entries contain only the entry data in each field and no additional markup like links. If you want the items in your bibliography linked to something, then the 'right' way to do that is to modify the bibliography style to apply the link - not to include the link in each field manually.